# Get content of multiple div tags with same class name

Tags: php, html

I read this article - [Get DIV content from external Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446598/get-div-content-from-external-website) . I get source of website with `file_get_contents()` function and I have to extract from it content of two divs with same class name.

I have very similar problem, but with divs with same class name. E.g. I have code like that:

```
<div class="baaa">
Some conete
</div>
<div class="baaa">
Second Content
</div>
```

I want to get both content of both these divs. Solution accepted in article I linked support only one. My expected result is array like this:

```
$divs[0] = "Some conete"
$divs[1] = "Second Content"
```

Please give me advice what to do. I read about DOMDocument class, but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Use each function in JQuery to get value of all div tags.
`$(".baaa").each(function(){});

Comment: try to use `preg_match_all()`

Comment: @bcesars I need to use PHP

Comment: @violator667 Can you explain?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761115/find-div-with-class-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser

Comment: @Ty221 ok - wait a sec ;-)

Answer (score 1):

i have used the simple html dom parser and your content can be extracted as

```
$html = file_get_html('your html file link');
$k=1;
foreach($html->find('div.baaa') as $e){
        $divs[$k]=$e;
        $k++;
    }
echo $divs[1]."<br>";
echo $divs[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPath. XPath is a query language for XML. There are PHP functions that support Xpath.
For you the example could be:

File `test.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="baaa">
Some conete
</div>
<div class="baaa">
Second Content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The php code that extracts contents of divs with the class "baaa"

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.html');
$data = $xml->xpath('//div[@class="baaa"]/text()');
foreach($data as $row) {
    printf($row);
}
```

generates the following output:

```
Some conete
Second Content
```

Look for XPath tutorials if you need more complex searching or analyzing.

Answer (score -1):

Try it with your data:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents('http://address.com');
preg_match_all('/<div class=\"baaa\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$file_contents,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

BTW: Polska rządzi :)

Comment: To prawda - Polska rządzi :D

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.baaa').each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
</script>

<div class="baaa">
Some conete
</div>
<div class="baaa">
Second Content
</div>
```

Comment: He said he needs to use PHP