# Finding all divs with a certain class in a HTML document

Tags: php, html

Using PHP, how can I extract all `<div class="this">` even though it appears on different hierarchical levels in a HTML document?

```
<h3>Hello</h3>
<p>World</p>
<div class="this">
    (lots of random markup, including other divs)
</div>
<div class="this">
    (more random markup, including other divs)
</div>
<div class="inside">
    <div class="this">
        (even more random markup, including other divs)
    </div>
</div>
<p>Bye.</p>
```

If it's not possible to achieve with regular expressions, does PHP have a built-in library that makes it easy to do something like this (pseudo-code)?

```
$result = find_all($html, "div", "this");
```

Desired result:

```
$result = array(
'<div class="this">
    (lots of random markup, including other divs)
</div>',
'<div class="this">
    (more random markup, including other divs)
</div>',
'<div class="this">
    (even more random markup, including other divs)
</div>',
);
```

Comment: do a search for php html parser, it's probably the easiest way rather than a regex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761115/find-div-with-class-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser

Comment: This library seems very good! So there's no simple way to accomplish the same thing with a built-in PHP library? I have to rely on an third-party extension such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for your work , your code is something like below lines :

```
    <?php
include_once "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = str_get_html('<h3>Hello</h3><p>World</p><div class="this"> (lots of random markup, including other divs)</div><div class="this"> (more random markup, including other divs)</div><div class="inside"> <div class="this"> (even more random markup, including other divs) </div></div><p>Bye.</p>');

$divs = $html->find('div.this');
$ans=array();
foreach($divs as $div){
$ans[]=$div->outertext;
}

print_r($ans);


?>
```

Comment: This works nicely! It requires a library, but is more user friendly and straight forward than the built-in DOMDocument.

Comment: @forthrin thanks , you can accept it , and help other user with this problem and improve this site

Answer (score 0):

PHP is mainly a HTML preprocessor. Well it is. So to do what you're asking you'd have to get the document using `get_file_contents()` or some AJAX to send the data to your php. The latter seems a bit extreme for what you've asked.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, I'd personally recommend 'saving' these divs somewhere else before processing them in PHP. Say like a database? Then you can dynamically build these elements based on data in the database.

Use JavaScript for any client side actions, in other words, anything after the page has been generated. Say like getting more data?

Comment: This answer seems irrelevant. The job needs to be done inside PHP without communication with servers and databases. It's about extracting data from a HTML document (served elsewhere).

Comment: well I'm sorry but I can't see a way of possibly doing what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Extract data from scraped HTML files that have a complex and unreliable hierarchical structure, but can be identified by tag attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read your file using [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) method `loadHTMLFile` or `loadHTML`.
After that is in a variable you can call `$instance->getElementsByTagName("div")` which will give you a [DOMNodeList](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). Then you `foreach` and filter the `DOMNode`s using `getAttribute("class")`.

Comment: It got this working too, but DOMDocument can be somewhat intimidating with how everything is wrapped into formal structures and must be accessed in a very "correct" way.