# how to get html table element by classname in php

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Here is a table whose classname is nick. I am trying to get this table by class name "nick".

```
<table  class="nick">
              <tbody>
              <tr>

                <th> a  </th>
                <th>    b</th>
                <th> c  </th>
          </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>

        </tbody></table>
```

here is the code.

```
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');

  $table = $html->find('.nick');
  echo $table . '<br>';

?>
```

when i get table by tagname it works but  when i get it by class name it shows the msg "Array to string conversion" and it returns "Array".

how can i get this table by class nick and its rows and coloms.Also threre are 2 table which has classname "nick".

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761115/find-div-with-class-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser (Try table.nick)

Comment: this question similar to like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761115/find-div-with-class-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to put the index inside `->find()`. Without providing the index, this will return an array. When you put the index (in this case `0`), you'll point to the first found element with that class.

```
$table = $html->find('.nick', 0);
                           // ^ this is important
echo $table;
```

[Reference:](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

> *mixed find ( string $selector [, int $index] )*
>
> *Find elements by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise return an array of object.*

Of course, the first table falls under zero index (`0`), the second on one (`1`).

If you want to go the extra mile, you can check first if there tables with that class name if you want the `->find()` method untouched:

```
$table = $html->find('.nick');
if(count($table) > 0) { // if found
    echo $table[0]; // echo first table
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get right html using class in php like below code.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');

$table = $html->find('table.nick');
//OR
$table = $html->find('table[class=nick]');
echo $table . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class name & index like below:

1st table :

```
$table1 = $html->find('table[class=nick]', 0);
```

2nd table :

```
$table2 = $html->find('table[class=nick]', 1);
```